# User data coming back undefined with Redux React App

Tags: reactjs, redux

Currently I am trying to pass user data through my react app with Redux.  I have created a user API with a django backend that is definately working, as I am able to go the url and see all the json that comes out of it.  However, when I try to pass it into a component I keep getting undefined.  Here is my code:

userActions.js:

```
import Axios from "axios";

    export function getUser() {
      const id = this.params.match.id
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchUserBegin());
        return Axios.get(`/api/user/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
              user: res.data,

          })
        })
      }
    }

    export const FETCH_USER_BEGIN   = 'FETCH_USER_BEGIN';
    export const FETCH_USER_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS';
    export const FETCH_USER_FAILURE = 'FETCH_USER_FAILURE';

    export const fetchUserBegin = () => ({
      type: FETCH_USER_BEGIN
    });

    export const fetchUserSuccess = user => ({
      type: FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: { user }
    });

    export const fetchUserFailure = error => ({
      type: FETCH_USER_FAILURE,
      payload: { error }
    });
```

userReducer.js

```
import {  FETCH_USER_BEGIN, FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, FETCH_USER_FAILURE  } from '../actions/actionTypes'


const initialState = {
    user: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_USER_BEGIN:
        // Mark the state as "loading" so we can show a spinner or something
        // Also, reset any errors. We're starting fresh.
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null
        };

      case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
        // All done: set loading "false".
        // Also, replace the items with the ones from the server
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          user: action.user
        };

      case FETCH_USER_FAILURE:
        // The request failed, but it did stop, so set loading to "false".
        // Save the error, and we can display it somewhere
        // Since it failed, we don't have items to display anymore, so set it empty.
        // This is up to you and your app though: maybe you want to keep the items
        // around! Do whatever seems right.
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error,
          user: {}
        };

      default:
        // ALWAYS have a default case in a reducer
        return state;
    }
  }
```

And the display component:

UserInformation.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";

class UserDetailView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getUser());
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    console.log(user)

    return (
      <ul>
        {user.map(user =>
          <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserDetailView);
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './store/reducers/auth';


const composeEnhances = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store  = createStore(reducer, composeEnhances(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
))

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>

)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Anyone got any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to `setState()` in that action creator:

```
 this.setState({
    user: res.data,
 })
```

you should **dispatch an action** instead

Try this:

```
export function getUser() {
      const id = this.params.match.id
      return dispatch => {
         dispatch(fetchUserBegin());
         return Axios.get(`/api/user/${id}`)
          .then( res => { 
            dispatch(fetchUserSuccess(res.data);
         })
       }
     }
```

You should pass the `mapDispatchToProps` function to the `connect()` method as the second argument, like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";

class UserDetailView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser()  //fixed
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    console.log(user)

    return (
      <ul>
        {user.map(user =>
          <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({   //added
  getUser: dispatch(getUser())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UserDetailView);  //fixed
```

And also fix this:

```
   case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
        // All done: set loading "false".
        // Also, replace the items with the ones from the server
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          user: action.payload.user  //fixed
        };
```

Comment: Gave me 'dispatch' is not defined

Comment: did you apply the `redux-thunk` middleware? please provide your store implementation

Comment: I sure didn't give me just a second, provided index.js with store implementation

Comment: back to getting undefined

Comment: well, I've updated my answer. then fixing you codes like that and let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: getting Cannot read property 'params' of  undefined.  But I am positive the api is at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/1

Comment: the issue comes from this line `const id = this.params.match.id`

Comment: However, I think the problem is with the whole application logic :) did you actually establish the application logic?

Comment: Totally a noob here, sorry about that.